# after Updating to spring-boot 2.6.3 I have the error to find class RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to update the application from spring-boot 2.0.2 to 2.6.3 but when I run the application I will face the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-25 09:50:38.369 ERROR 38484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               [User ] : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminReportsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gssnPlusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gssnPlusService' defined in file
```

Could you please let me know what is the problem that @Autowired doesn't work.
Thank you so much

Comment: Your `adminReportsController` bean cannot inject the `gssnPlusService` bean. Why? We cannot tell based on merely an error in a console window.